# When I Embed a website (wordpress blog) on my android app it opens in another browser?

Tags: android, wordpress

I just start android developing and I want to embed my website in the app.
When I want to open "http://www.google.com" , webpage opens in My app, but when I change address to my blog it wants to open it on external browser.
This is My activity code that I used to embed my site!

```
public class WebPage extends Activity {

  @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_page);


    //web view start
    WebView med = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    med.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    med.getSettings().
    med.loadUrl("http://www.mediratour.com");
  }
}
```

My webpage based on wordpress, I don't know if I have to change settings to prevent using external browser and opens it in My app.

Thanks

Comment: Like is described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) go to the paragraph that explains the use of shouldOverrideUrlLoading and see the example:
If you want more control over where a clicked link load, create your own WebViewClient that overrides the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // Set this on your web view.
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());

// Create this class.
public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView webView, final String url) {
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }
}
```

I think it helps.